Why console.log on chrome console display undefined and does not print out value? What to do if I want to list a value?
Try this in chrome console:


var x =2;
console.log(x);



Why console.log() on chrome console display undefined and does not print out value? Is there anything wrong in my setting?
What to do if I want to list a value on the console?
P.S. add an image to show the output on console

It works for me, and I'm using Chrome.  Does it work for you when you run the snippet above?

Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing? This code should normally work just fine.

"Is there anything wrong in my setting?" - probably. What is your setting?

Are you saying it doesn’t show 2 at all, or that 2 is followed by undefined?

Yes, the 2 is not shown. only undefined.
The code works in different other browsers so it may be the problem of chrome.
The pc has been rebooted first to test this.

As tested, this appears only to one of my chrome profile. So it may be due to the setting is wrong or possibly caused by extension installed. Further testing needed.

Your code should be giving the below output in console -
2
undefined

Browser console also prints return value of the last statement method or function call. Return value of console.log() is undefined so it prints undefined also.
Try these cases -
Case 1:
function log(y){
    console.log(y);
    return y + 1;
};
var x = 2;
log(2);

Output -
2 - console.log(y)
3 - return value of log(x)

Case 2:
function log(y){
    console.log(y);
    return y + 1;
};
var x = 2;
log(x);
console.log(x);

Output -
2 - console.log(y)
2 - console.log(x)
undefined - return value of console.log(x)

Case 3:
function log(y){
    console.log(y);
    return y + 1;
};
var x = 2;
console.log(x);
log(x);

Output -
2 - console.log(x)
2 - console.log(y)
3 - return value of log(x)


This answer doesn't answer why the OP is getting undefined from this code: var x = 2; console.log(x); . There's no function or return in the OP's example.

I reset the chrome inspector using the suggested method below and it works fine now.
How to reset chrome inspector?

And all my snippets gone. Not a good method but it works.
